# Sum(Iff() in report

Tags: ms-access, sum, report, iif, expressionbuilder

I'm working on a report and would like to have a summary in the report footer for each section of the report.

The summary will include tickets open <30 days

In the report I've created a textbox and am using the below as the Control Source.

```
=Sum(IIf([qryDMIncidents-Client-ACTIVE-PENDINGCOLUMBIA].[Days Old]<30,1,0))
```

This will work in a query as an expression, however it does not work in the Control Source Expression Builder. Why? I do not know?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should work if you reference a control on the report instead of a field in its record source.

For example, if the report design includes a text box named *txtDaysOld* whose Control Source is `[Days Old]`, use this ...

```vb
=Sum(IIf([txtDaysOld]<30,1,0))
```

If the report doesn't already include a similar text box, add one.  And the text box does not need to be visible for that `=Sum()` expression to work.